# Golang Mongodb Filter Queries as a string

Tags: mongodb, go

I try to write queries for mongodb collection in Golang. However to use db.Collection.find() method we need to add filter in an interface{} type. I can use bson.D and bson.M to create filters. However, The user will send as a string these filters to backend side. For example:

In Golang:

```
filter := `bson.D{ // a string variable sent by UI
   {"$and",
      bson.A{
         bson.D{{"rating", bson.D{{"$gt", 7}}}},
         bson.D{{"rating", bson.D{{"$lte", 10}}}},
      },
   },
}`
```

How can I convert dynamic string filter to interface{} type for accepting by find() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think one workaround for parse query string could be the query string from UI could be raw json like `{"$and": [{"rating": {"$gt": 7}}, {"rating": {"$lte", 10}]}`, then you could parse it through [bson.UnmarshalExtJSON](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#UnmarshalExtJSON)

Sample codes

```golang
filterStr := `{"$and": [{"rating": {"$gt": 7}}, {"rating": {"$lte", 10}]}`
var filter interface{}
err := bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(filterStr), true, &filter)

// the filter could be passed to Find() method
```

Comment: This works fine as long as you don't use functions such as `datetime.datetime.now()`. How can we handle such cases? For example: `{"creationDate": {"$lt": datetime.datetime.now()}}`.